# error in php not logging or displaying

Tags: php, log-files, php.ini

I can not get any errors to display on screen on write to a log file.  When  check phpinfo() print out I have same value of master a local for

```
display_errors On 
display_startup_errors On
error_log /var/log/php.log
error_reporting E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
log_errors On
log_errors_max_len
```

> ls -l /var/log/php.log is 
>   -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 Jun 21 07:47 /var/log/php.log for /var and /varlog drwxrwxrwx  23 root root  4096 Jun  2 11:13 var

when there is an error in the code the page the browsers shows nothing and browser says there is no source for the page.
Any suggestions of where else to look or change to errors to appear somewhere (anywhere would be good)

**edit:** my error script is now

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "print from error.php 2 ";
error                        
//print from erroerror to cuase logging to happen.
?>
```

this will print on display and to log

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant error - assumed 'error' in /var/www/piku_dev2/error.php on line 7
```

but if I put garbage like   #@$%$ on the error line I get nor error messages anywhere.

**Edit2:**
The problem turned out to in the httpd.conf file.  I don't know what it was yet as it was fixed y someone else.

Comment: It's possible to use `error_reporting()` to change the error reporting level during run-time. But how do you know this is caused by a PHP error? And this is an unlikely scenario, but the script could be using the error suppression operator `@` and just terminating the script with `die` before any output is printed.

Answer (score 7):

I can see a few possible solutions to your problem. These are the most common issues you'll run into:

- In your example, you use `#@$%$` to induce an error. However, PHP treats any line beginning with a hash as a comment, so this line would never be evaluated, hence it would never trigger an error condition.
- There are 2 distinct `php.ini` files that you should be aware of; one for Apache and one for the PHP CLI. Make sure that the one you've edited is the one for Apache if your script is being called from a web browser. The directory that this file is found in will vary from distro to distro, but the default path is usually a slight variation of `/etc/php/apache/php.ini`
- You *must* restart Apache after making changes to the `php.ini` file, or send a SIGHUP to Apache to force a re-read of the configuration file.
- The `error_reporting` and `log_errors` configuration variables can be overwritten locally within an Apache vhost file, or even in the PHP script itself. Make sure that the default server config does not overwrite these variables locally in the Apache configuration for the vhost you're using.
- The permissions of your `/var/log/php.log` file need to be writeable by Apache. It's usually safe to set the owner of this file to the Apache user on your system (the Apache user is usually either `www-data` or `apache`).

Comment: Thanks, this helps me. I have to create a target log file and set permission and owner to `www-data`. This is on ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the **display_errors** or **error_reporting** were overridden by something else.

It happened to me by an application that changes the error_reporting later in the bootstrap which I didn't see.

A good practice is to search for error_reporting within the application and see it is modified somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, I had no error logs in two cases:

1. The user under which Apache was running had no permissions to modify `php_error_log` file.
2. Error 500 occurred because of bad configuration of `.htaccess`, for example wrong rewrite module settings. In this situation errors are logged to Apache `error_log` file.

Answer (score -1):

My issue was that not only was apache not able to write to the log files, it also wasn't able to write to the /var/log/httpd directory.

My fix?

php.ini
error_log = /var/log/httpd/php-error.log

chmod 777 /var/log
chmod 777 /var/log/httpd

I'm running CentOS 6 by the way. There has to be a better way than chmod'ing your log and httpd folder to 777, but this was the only way I could get it to work. You could add apache to the root group, which would be a bad idea.